# \onecolumn introducing empty page

Tags: tables, two-column

I have a 1.5-page two-column table in a two-column document, which I created with `\onecolumn` and xtabular. Unfortunately, this introduces an empty page before the table. How can I remove this empty page?

The table structure:

```
\documentclass{iosart2c}
[...]
\afterpage{
\onecolumn
\label{tab:[...]}
\bottomcaption{[...]}

\begin{xtabular*}{[...]}
[...]
\end{xtabular*}
\twocolumn
}
```

Removing the afterpage statement does'nt help and changing bottomcaption to topcaption instead creates a page with only the caption on it.

Comment: Any pointer for the `iosart2c` class?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn` use the package multicol, which was written for advanced use of columns.

---

Edit:

One can download this class here: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/81111536/ . It seems to be a class for publishing in a journal. So we can't tinker with the code.

Probably the only solution which will be accepted is something like this:

```
\documentclass{iosart2c}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

  \blindtext

  \begin{table*}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
    This is a pretty long tabular cell & And this as well but go to hell.\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried multicol now but it seems like it only works on one-column mode, not when your document class already defines two columns.

Comment: The problem with table* is that it does not work for tables longer than a single page.

Comment: @KonradHöffner Well, and longtable? Supertabular?